# How to cache query data in node with redis

Tags: node.js, postgresql, caching, express, redis

I´m building an API in Node with Express, Postgresql and Redis and I´m a complete beginner when it comes to node. I´m trying to setup redis to cache the query response from postgres but I just can´t figure out how to do it without repeating the implementation in every file.

Here´s some of my app.js

```
// connect to the postgresql database 
var database = require("./config/database")(app);
var pg = require("pg"); 
var conString = app.get('db uri');
var client = new pg.Client(conString); client.connect();

// an example of how my routes look like
app.get('/v1/users/:uid', users.getUser(client));
```

Here´s users.js

```
exports.getUser = function(client) {
    return function(req, res) {
    var userId = req.params.uid;

    var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id = ?",[userId]);

    query.on("row", function (row, result) {
      result.addRow(row);
    });

    query.on("end", function (result) {
      res.json(result.rows);
    });

  };
};
```

Ive searched all over the web including stackoverflow and the closest solution I´ve found can be found on this page [using redis for cahing in node](http://blog.stevenlu.com/2013/03/07/using-redis-for-caching-in-nodejs/)
His solution looks like this:

```
var handler = function(response)
{
   response = JSON.stringify(response);
   client.setex('some-key-value', 21600, response);     
   res.end(response);
};

client.get('some-key-value', function (err, result) {
   if (err || !result)
      execute_function(zipcode, handler);
   else
      res.end(result);
});
```

I´ve got it sort of working by wrapping everything inside the client.get if/else statement but it looks ugly and since I have many routes I would end up repeating alot of code, any help of how I can get this solution working with my code would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: We're about to do the same thing, expect with MySQL, Hapi and Redis. Did you manage to find any docs or examples?

Comment: @AdrianLynch No sorry, I never got it to work and couldn´t find any examples that could help me.

Answer (score -3):

One of the command problems in Javascript development is Spaghetti callbacks.

You can use https://github.com/kriskowal/q, promises to avoid such mistakes and enable you to build a cleaner codes or you can use https://github.com/caolan/async, this to handle your callbacks as well.

One of the biggest advantages in working on Node.js project, is the community behind it. So, you can search for suitable npm packages to help you to build your project.